# Ruby autoload throws error on first mention of constant

Tags: ruby, autoload

I'm trying to set up autoloading for my classes in a new project of mine using `Module#autoload`. It's almost working - the issue is that on first using a constant to be autoloaded, it errors with "uninitialized constant", but on second usage the constant works as expected.

Code illustrating problem:

init.rb:

```
# Load lib, other directories will be autoloaded
APPLICATION_ROOT=File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
$:.unshift(APPLICATION_ROOT)
Dir.glob("#{APPLICATION_ROOT}/patches/*").each {|p| require p}
Dir.glob("#{APPLICATION_ROOT}/lib/*").each {|p| require p}

# Test autoloading
include Autoload
begin
  puts Sprite.new.inspect
rescue
  puts "Caught an error"
end
puts Sprite.new.inspect # will not error
```

patches/string.rb:

```
class String
  def camelize
    self.split("_").map{|word| word.capitalize}.join
  end
end
```

lib/autoload.rb:

```
module Autoload
  Dir.glob("#{APPLICATION_ROOT}/app/*/*").each do |path|
    classname = File.basename(path).gsub(/.rb$/,'').camelize
    autoload classname.to_sym, path
  end
end
```

app/models/sprite.rb:

```
puts "Sprite Required!"
class Sprite
  puts "Sprite Defining!"
  def initialize
    puts "Sprite Initialized!"
  end
end
puts "Sprite Defined!"
```

The output:

```
Sprite Required!
Sprite Defining!
Sprite Defined!
Caught an error
Sprite Initialized!
#<Sprite:0x000000024ee920>
```

How can I obtain my desired behavior (no initial error)?

Comment: Does it work if you `autoload :Sprite, "sprite"` explicitly?  What does `autoload?(:Sprite)` get you after the call to the Autoload module?

Comment: No difference with doing it explicitly, `autoload?(:Sprite)` returns nil at all points in `init.rb` which is rather curious as it does end up loading it in the end..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `autoload` in the scope of the module `Autoload`. In a case like that what ruby is expecting or creating is an autoload for the symbol `Autoload::Sprite`, when what you want is just `Sprite`.

Fortunately the fix is simple:

```
module Autoload
  def self.included(mod)
    # ...
    # Call autoload on the scope of the includer
    mod.autoload ...
  end
end
```

Or you could also explicitly call autoload on `Object`, since that's where your "target scope" for the autoloaded classes most likely is:

```
Object.autoload ...
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's creating a symbol for `Autoload::Sprite` as using that instead doesn't work (and it doesn't explain to me why it errors, then works). Defining the autoload on include works properly though, thanks!